# How do you perform a Group By function on a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, group-by

I am working with a database which has Contacts, Messages, Recipients, and Conversations.

I performed a full outer join on between Contacts and Recipients using user_ID as the criteria. This would give a table with these values; USER_ID, FNAME, LNAME, CELL, CITY, COUNTRY, MSGID, USER_ID, TIME_READ. There are duplicate values for user_ID since both tables had this values. My sub query give the correct result when done on it's own:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
FULL JOIN Recipients
ON Contacts.user_ID=Recipients.user_ID;
```

After I do this I want to preform a Group By where they count each msgID for each user_ID, to give an end result of user_ID and the number of messages each user got.

I can't seem to get the syntax correct, since I keep getting an error.

```
SQL> SELECT user_ID, count(msgID)
FROM (  SELECT *
    FROM Contacts
    FULL JOIN Recipients
    ON Contacts.user_ID=Recipients.user_ID)
Group by Contacts.user_ID; 

Group by Contacts.user_ID
         *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: "CONTACTS"."USER_ID": invalid identifier
```

I've tried "Contacts.user_ID" and just plain "user_ID" but it doesn't like either variation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.user_ID, r.user_ID), COUNT(*)
FROM Contacts c FULL JOIN
     Recipients r
     ON c.user_ID = r.user_ID
GROUP BY COALESCE(c.user_ID, r.user_ID);
```

The subquery is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I wanted!